# How Do I get searchlogic to work with rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, searchlogic

I put searchlogic in my gemfile... and now my rails server won't start :(

this is the errormessage

```
gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `merge_joins' for class `Class' (NameError)
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/searchlogic-2.4.27/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:8:in `included'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/searchlogic-2.4.27/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `class_eval'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/searchlogic-2.4.27/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `included'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/searchlogic-2.4.27/lib/searchlogic.rb:34:in `include'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/searchlogic-2.4.27/lib/searchlogic.rb:34
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/glowing-rain-75/config/application.rb:7
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
 from /Users/omiohoro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6
```

How Do I fix this? Thanks in advance 
cheers tabaluga

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's the [railsdog's searchlogic fork](http://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic) on github that supports Rails 3.

You can add it to your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git'
```

Comment: It also doesn't work for me on Rails 3.2 - lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:45:in `method_missing': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Comment: I have had the same issue as John Douthat.

Answer (score 9):

In rails 3, you could use [meta_search](http://github.com/ernie/meta_search) instead.

It is very similar to searchlogic but

```
<%= order @search, :by => :name, :as => "Order By Name" %>
```

is changed to

```
<%= sort_link @search, :name, "Order By Name" %>
```

Comment: Matt has answered the way to get back searchlogic :D Actually meta_search works just like searchlogic and after replacing those `order` to `sort_link`, it should works as expected ^^